# How to turn a 3D model into a normal map?

Tags: uv, texture-baking, normal-map

Not sure the title really explains it, but I have a high poly flower model that I want to turn the top-down view of into a normal map (or other solution?) so that it can be put onto a plane

I figured I could just bake the shape onto the plane but it came out blank unless I went wrong somewhere.

Is this possible? It's for importing into Substance Painter

Comment: You need to bake the normals, maybe share your file so that we can check if there's a problem?

Comment: You are just interested in the top view right?

Answer (score 0):

Ah I found it! Turns out I forgot to click 'select to active' when baking. Squashing the model has made it work out